# How to proxy a static snapshot of scala 2.10.3

Tags: scala, sbt

Scala 2.10.3 has a bug fix my team needs; but, I don't want to subject my group to a constantly changing version (using 2.10.3-SNAPSHOT). How can I download the latest snapshot, publish it to my local nexus (say 2.10.3-FOO) and have sbt use it? I'm familiar with proxy-ing and did get sbt to use our nexus repository to download the renamed scala-lang, scala-compiler. However, it never downloads scala-reflect and bombs out. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried the beta of sbt 0.13.0?

Comment: Would you clarify how that would help? Wouldn't that require a 0.13.0 version of all my plugins?

Comment: From what I vaguely remember overhearing, SBT 0.13 has improved handling of custom Scala builds. Maybe that would be of help to you. Don't know about plugins though.

Answer (score 0):

I found that pulling down scala.git and publishing a local build to our nexus repo using the ant tasks provided allowed me to accomplish what I was after. In terms of sbt, the documented way of using a proxy repo (-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true, using the repositories file) worked well.